# get the closest points

Tags: java

Let's say I have a bunch of points:

[image]

What is the best way to get a certain amount of closest neighbors.
For example I wan't the 8 closest points for point no 57.

This without using brute force.

O yeah, if possible, it would be great if it's efficient for moving points as well.

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of all the points? Seems like a stupid question but I have to ask...

Comment: Also: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14373/given-a-list-of-2d-locations-and-sizes-how-can-i-efficiently-find-the-nearest-o

Comment: This question might also help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79842/efficiently-detecting-objects-inside-multiple-radius/79845#79845

Comment: Basically, look up spatial partitioning and nearest neighbor algorithms.